# Problems with AsynkTaskLoader in C# Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Please, somebody help me about implementation AsynckTaskLoader in Xamarin.Android, I don't found anything on the web and I really need help with this. Please a example or something that it could help but en C# language.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question is too broad as-is. If you have a question about a specific problem or bit of code, ask that instead.

Comment: What do you mean by AsyncTaskLoader?

Comment: it performs async loads. With the lifecycle of android.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.AsyncTaskLoader/).
It contains an example implementation of an AsyncTaskLoader subclass that loads the currently installed applications from the package manager.